# how to use Python to send email without exposing password?

Tags: python, email

This snippet works but the password in the code is wide open:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("usrname", "pw")

msg = "\nHello!" # The /n separates the message from the headers
server.sendmail("me@gmail.com", "u@gmail.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

I'm wondering how to do this securely.

edit:

I'm looking for "keystorage" solutions, like one used by any real email client, which stores your password securely (hopefully) on the disk.

Comment: `input()` (or `raw_input()` in python 2)?

Comment: Does this problem have anything to do with Python or email?

Comment: Are you looking for ideas in the line of “store pw in a different file”, “ask for the pw every time”, “use keystorage solutions”?

Comment: I'm looking for "keystorage" solutions, like one used by any real email client, which stores your password securely (hopefully) on the disk

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [getpass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) module.  You can use getpass to prompt for a password, so that it is not stored in the code.

**Usage:**

```
>>> import getpass
>>> password = getpass.getpass()
Password: 
>>> print password
s3cr3t
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can:

use env variable e.g.:`export PWD=xx`, then in python:`import os; pwd = os.environ.get('PWD')`

use a file record the password, and then put it in a other location. then `with open(passwdfile) as fi: pwd=fi.read().strip()`

And if your smtp server suppoort ,recommand use ssl.

Comment: that's better than what I have, though I'd like to have some sort of encryption on the pwd. storing it plainly doesn't feel comfortable to me.